# No manual entry for make

Tags: linux, make, man

I'm trying to read man pages for make on my server and they are not there.  Man pages for other linux commands and built-ins, however, are there.

Does anyone know why this is and how to fix?

Thanks.

```
man make
No manual entry for make
```

Comment: Is `make` installed?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know `make` was it's own package.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know `make` is it's own package.  All I had to do is install it.  Credit to Darth Android...

To install:  `sudo aptitude install make`.

Comment: For a deeper understanding of `make`, additionally to the manpage, you might consider reading the `info` documentation (`info make`).

Comment: Thanks @AndreasWiese.  What's the difference between `info` and `man`?

Comment: `info` is the hypertext manual format of the GNU project and if there exists an `info` manual, it's most likely much more comprehensive than the corresponding manpage.  You could see `man` as the short reference and `info` as the handbook.  If you need a better `info` reader than standard `info`, have a look at [`pinfo`](http://pinfo.sourceforge.net/).